# iOS iTunes Connect confusion

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm ready to submit my app for review.
In iTunes Connect, what is a DEMO ACCOUNT username and password? First of all where do I find this username and password? Is it considered my Apple ID and password  I use to sign into iTunes Connect or is this a particular DEMO ACCOUNT username and password some other type of information? If it is, where do I get this username and password?

In iTunes Connect, do I need a privacy policy?  I have Button for Twitter and Facebook share. When you're currently signed in FB and/or Twitter you can post your scores on Twitter/Facebook by clicking on share in my button. However, you can't login to FB or Twitter by clicking the button in my app. You'd have to log in to FB and Twitter in the Settings app which has nothing to do with my app. Also, I have game center integrated and every once in a while if you're not signed in when the app starts up it'll pop up and you can login to GameCenter in my app. Do I need privacy policy then and if so where do I get one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demo account is an account that you create yourself and provide the details to the review team so that they can review your app without using their personal accounts (which they won't). So, if you're app has a Facebook Login, just create a Facebook account for testing, and give the review team the username and password. If your app doesn't require the user to login, you can ignore that section.

As for the privacy policy, if you don't provide a custom privacy policy, the default one will apply. For your scenario, you probably don't need a custom privacy policy at this point, or you would have known about it.

Good luck with the review process!

Comment: You can't log in to Facebook in my app if you're currently logged out. When you click the FB button it tells you to go to Settings App and log in to there. Once the user is logged in then they can use the FB button to share information. I have this for FB and Twitter. However, if you're not logged into Game Center and Game Center login pops up in my app, there you can log into your Game Center account.

So do I need demo account for Game Center?

Comment: If the user can use your app without logging in, you don't have to include any details. But, if you don't want to provide the review team with any additional reasons to reject the app, you can include demo account information for all relevant social networks and/or other accounts that can be associated with your app. Then they can choose whether to use it or not. You can provide the details and any additional information in the comments field next to the Demo account details section on the app's submission page.